# Join Array of strings except empty

Tags: arrays, string, vbscript

I try to find an easy way to concatenate strings from an array - but only if they are not empty.

Example:

```vb
Dim strArr(3)
strArr(0) = "This"
strArr(1) = "is"
strArr(2) = ""
strArr(3) = "a"
strArr(4) = "test"

strResult = Join(strArr, "***")
MsgBox strResult
```

will result in this text: `This***is******a***test`

but it should be: `This***is***a***test`

So the empty string should be ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Option Explicit

Dim aStrArray
    aStrArray = Array("", "", "This", "", "", "is", "", "", "", "a", "test", "", "")

Dim strResult    
    strResult = MyJoin(aStrArray, "***")
    WScript.Echo strResult


Function MyJoin( inputArray, inputDelimiter )
Dim delimiter
    delimiter = Chr(1) & Chr(2) 
    With New RegExp
        .Pattern =  "^(?:" & delimiter & ")+" & _ 
                    "|(?:" & delimiter & ")+$" & _ 
                    "|(?:" & delimiter & ")+(" & delimiter & ")"
        .Global = True 
        MyJoin = Replace(.Replace(Join(inputArray, delimiter), "$1"), delimiter, inputDelimiter)
    End With
End Function
```

You can replace multiple occurrences of the delimiter with only one.

In the function in sample code:

1. A delimiter is defined to be used to join all the elements in the input array. It is created to reduce the probability of finding it inside the data.
2. A regular expression is created to handle initial, end and repeated occurences of the delimiter.
3. The input array is joined using the generated delimiter
4. The regular expression is used to remove non desired delimiter sequences
5. The generated delimiter is replaced by the input delimiter

Comment: Seems that there is no built-in-way to handle this. Will use that function since it avoids problems if the delimiter is part of the text.

Answer (score 1):

Next code snippet could help (and even `ReDim`s the `strArr`):

```
option explicit
Dim strArr, strResult, strJoinString
ReDim strArr(4)
strArr(0) = "This"
strArr(1) = "is"
strArr(2) = ""
strArr(3) = "a"
strArr(4) = "test"

strJoinString = "€€€"
strResult = Join(strArr, strJoinString)
Do While Instr(1, strResult, strJoinString & strJoinString, vbBinaryCompare) > 0
  strResult = Replace( strResult, strJoinString & strJoinString, strJoinString)
Loop
strArr = Split(strResult, strJoinString)
strResult = Join(strArr, "***")

MsgBox strResult & vbNewLine & Join(strArr, "-")
```

Make sure `strJoinString` does not match any array element!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to copy all non-empty fields to a dictionary, then join the values of that dictionary:

```
Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 0 To UBound(strArr)
  If strArr(i) <> "" Then d.Add i, strArr(i)
Next

WScript.Echo Join(d.Items, "***")
```